# Laptop won't recognize standard hard disc but will recognize SSD

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd

Working on a Lenovo ThinkPad which was dropped.

Oddly enough it won't recognize it's own (standard) hard disk or boot from the CD/DVD drive, but will recognize an SSD and boot via USB - I'm at a loss to explain why. Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Is the HDD being picked up in the BIOS?  Can you hook it up externally and see if it spins up?

Comment: Yeah it spins, in fact I recovered the data from it, it does list in the bios, but doesn't appear to be bootable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a spare drive that's clean and empty, try to install Windows on it and see if it boots. Pretty bizzare but just another reason to sell the client on a new SSD.